# How do I fetch value of an object which resides under array of objects?

Tags: reactjs

https://api.covid19india.org/data.json

I want to access value of `totalconfirmed` from `cases_time_series` which is an array of objects. Also data are updated everyday. So I need only the value of last element of the array.

Comment: Please review [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section. Please add the minimal amount of the data needed to the question instead of posing a link to whole json. You also should post some code to show the effort you already did. Thank you.

Comment: Okay sure. It's my first time. I'm really sorry. I won't ask again like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
console.log(cases_time_series[cases_time_series.length - 1].totalconfirmed);
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to get data from such an endpoint, you should follow these steps:

1. **Get data with an HTTP call.** You can do this simply by native [`fetch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) API, [`Axios`](https://github.com/axios/axios), or other available methods like `Ajax` or `xhttp`. I will go with the preferred one which is `fetch`.

Your code should be something like this:

```js
fetch('https://api.covid19india.org/data.json')
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

2. **For iterating through an array you can simply loop it with available array helpers** like [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/map), or available others, or simply do this with traditional [`for`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for) loop. But in your particular case, the returned data from the endpoint is not an array itself but **it is an object with a large array reside inside it. So you should first get the object by its name.**

I will go with the `map` since **we need to return an array of `totalconfirmed` cases**, Here is the implementation:

```js
fetch("https://api.covid19india.org/data.json")
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => {
    const totalConfirmed = data.cases_time_series.map((item) => item.totalconfirmed);
    console.log(totalConfirmed);
  });
```